# Understanding Perl Script for GPIB Interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl, scripting, gpib

I am new to the perl and python. As a part of my job currently I am asked to convert the perl script to python. The purpose of this script is to automate the task of the magnum tester and parametric analyzer. Is any of you able to understand what the get_gpib_status function trying to do ??. Specific questions are

1. What does if(/Error/) mean in perl ?
2. What does it mean by

   ```
           chomp;
           s/\+//g;
           $value = $_;
           $foundError = 0;
   ```

   in perl?. What is the python equivalent of the get_gpib_status function ??.

   Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. The Script is as shown below.

   ```
   BEGIN {unshift(@INC, "." , ".." , 
   "\\Micron\\Nextest\\perl_modules");}


   use runcli;                                                                     
   # Enable input from perl script as nextest cli command, Runcli is the 
   command 
   that you’ll use to communicate with the tester
   use getHost;                                                                    
   # To latch in module/ "library into current script, here the 
   getHost.pm 
   is 
   loaded, used once on nextest system



   #open FILE,">","iv.txt" or die $!;                                              
   # Make file ready for reading from FILE


   $k=148;                                                                         
   # Time period T = 38ns corresponds to data value of 140
   #$i=0;
   while($k<156)
   {
   $i=3;
   while($i<4)
   {
   #$logfile = "vpasscp8stg_SS_vppmode"."stg"."$i"."freq"."$k".".txt";             
   # Give the name to the logfile
   #open(LOG,">$logfile") or die $!;                                               
   # Makes the file ready for reading from LOG


   #******************* SUBS ****************************

   if($i==3)
   {

   runcli("gpibinit;");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:MODE SWEEP\")");                              
   # PAGE, CHANnel, MODE, Set the mode to sweep

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU1:VNAME 'Vout'\")");                       
   # Source Monitor Unit, voltage name Vout
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU1:INAME 'Iout'\")");                       
   # current name Iout
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU1:MODE V\")");                             
   # voltage output node
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU1:FUNCTION VAR1\")");                      
   # function Variable

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU2:VNAME 'Vcc'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU2:INAME 'Icc'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU2:MODE V\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU2:FUNCTION CONSTANT\")");                  
   # function constant

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU3:VNAME 'Vpp'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU3:INAME 'Ipp'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU3:MODE V\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU3:FUNCTION CONSTANT\")");

   #runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU3:DIS\")");

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:SMU4:DIS\")");

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:VSU1:DIS\")");                                
   # Voltage Source Unit DISabled

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:CHAN:VSU2:DIS\")");

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:DISP:LIST:SELECT 'Vout'\")");                      
   # DISPlay LIST
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:DISP:LIST:SELECT 'Iout'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:DISP:LIST:SELECT 'Vcc'\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:DISP:LIST:SELECT 'Icc'\")");




   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:MODE SINGLE\")");                  
   # Single Stair Sweep
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:SPACING LINEAR\")");               
   # The sweep is incremented (decremented) by the
   # stepsize until the stop value is reached.

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:START 2.8\")");                    
   # Setting the sweep range of Vout
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:STOP 18\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:STEP 0.1\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:COMPLIANCE 0.05\")");              
   # Compliance: meaning the stable state of voltage, on the parametric 
   analyzer
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:VAR1:PCOMPLIANCE:STATE 
   0\")");         
   # PCOMPLIANCE: Might be the state before the stable state

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:DEL 2\")");                                   
   # Delay
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:HTIM 50\")");                                 
   # Hold Time

   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:CONS:SMU2:SOURCE 3.3\")");              
   # Setting the values for VCC
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:CONS:SMU2:COMP 0.1\")");
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:CONS:SMU3:SOURCE 12\")");               
   # Setting the values for VPP
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:MEAS:SWEEP:CONS:SMU3:COMP 0.1\")");


   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":PAGE:SCON:SING\")");

   sleep(2);
   runcli("ctst");
   runcli("stst");
   sleep(2);
   runcli("pu;rs");
   runcli("B16R_vpasscp_vpp.txt()");
   runcli("regaccess(static_load,0x9,0x9,$k)");                                    
   # Using the Cregs 0x9 to modulate the frequency
   runcli("adputr(0xcf,0x03)");
   runcli("rs");
   poll_4156c();
   }




   sub poll_4156c{
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":STAT:OPER:COND?\");");                                  
   # This command returns the present status of the Operation
   # Status "CONDITION" register. Reading this register does not clear 
   it.
   runcli("gpibreceive(0x1);");
   while((get_gpib_status() > 0)&&($foundError < 1) ){
   sleep(3);
   runcli("gpibsend(0x1,\":STAT:OPER:COND?\")");
   runcli("gpibreceive(0x1);");
   }

   }#end poll_4156c subroutine





   sub get_gpib_status{
   # get file info
   $host_meas = getHost();                                                         
   # Retrieve the nextest station detail, will return something like 
   mav2pt 
   - 0014
   $file_meas = $host_meas."_temp.cli";                                            
   # Define the file_meas as the nextest cli temporary file, Contains 
   all 
   the text as displayed on Nextest CLI
   open(STATUS, "$file_meas" ) || die("Can't open logfile: $!");
   print "\nSTATUS received from GPIB:";
   while(<STATUS>)
   {
   if(/Error/){
   runcli("gpibinit;");
   $foundError = 1;
   }
   else
   {
   chomp;
   s/\+//g;
   $value = $_;
   $foundError = 0;
   }
   } # End of while(<INMEAS>) loop.
   close(STATUS);
   #print "value = $value";
   return($value);
   }#End of get_gpib_status subroutine.


   $i=$i+1;
   }
   $k=$k+8;
   }
   ```

Comment: Well...in Perl chomp is a function that should (depending on the version of PERL) delete a newline from the end of a variable as long as the variable contains a string.  It shouldn't do anything to a string not ending in a newline.  Chomp will return the number of characters that got chomped...    When you ask about a gpib status you are talking about (probably) a General Purpose Interface Board that your program is supposed to communicate across to do its business.   You really have a big learning curve to get to the top of PERL like this...just saying

Comment: @Drt "Perl", not PERL ;) Perl is the name of the language, `perl` is the name of the actual binary. Neither are acronyms.

Comment: @stevieb  Thanks.  I stated PERL for emphasis thinking about how anybody would get over that hump let along convert from Perl to Python....  Your comments are correct.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dr t and stevieb. I was able to convert the same to python with the help of your comments

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1. `/Error/` is a regular expression matching any string that contains "Error" as its substring; in this context (`if(/Error/`) it is evaluated as boolean expression, ie. it is true if match is found in `$_` variable;

Ad. 2. `chomp` removes trailing newline character from its argument, or in lack of argument, from `$_` variable; `s/\+//g;` replaces any `+` signs found in `$_` with nothing (ie. removes them). As you might have already noticed, many Perl constructs operate on `$_` if not specified otherwise.

`get_gpib_status` is defined in your script - `sub get_gpib_status` is the beginning of definition (in Perl, functions are defined using `sub` keyword, stands for "subroutine").

And finally, I offer my sincere condolences. Giving the task of rewriting a program from one language to another to someone without prior experience with either language is probably not the stupidest managerial decision I've heard of, but high on the list.

Comment: Thanks Blotosmetek. I was trying to understand s/\+//g since long. but this helped me figure out exactly what I need to do in python